# Global variables in Python with file names

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a Python 3 program with Tkinter, which is running under Windows 8.1.

I need to select two folders which will be used together in another function. Currently, I have two select file buttons, which open the select folder dialog box:

```
def select_file_1(self):
    global first_file
    first_file = filedialog.askdirectory()

def select_file_2(self):
    global second_file
    second_file = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

These work correctly: whenever the buttons are clicked, it comes up and asks for a directory.

Then, there is only one other time the first_file and second_file variables are used, which I also note as global variables before using them. This is when another button is selected:

```
def create_composite(self):
    global first_file
    global second_file

    f1 = open(first_file, "r")
    f2 = open(second_file, "r")
```

However, this results in the following error: `NameError: name 'first_file' is not defined` when trying to read the line above beginning with `f1 = open`.

If it helps for clarity, here is the relevant part of my interface in the screenshot below. select_file_1 is called by clicking the first choose file and select_file_2 is called by clicking the second choose file. Then, create_composite is called by clicking create class.

[image: screnshot for clarity]

Comment: I don't know what's causing your problem, but why not make them attributes of `self` instead? Like `self.first_file` and `self.second_file`. (or possibly even just `self.files`)

Comment: In 10+ years of programming in python, I've yet to use the `global` keyword.  If you're using it, chances are you should restructure your code.

Comment: @Gerrat, occasionally I refactor singleton classes into modules, then member variables turn into module globals - and methods turn into functions that use `global` :) Not sure if it's a good pattern though... or if singletons are.

Comment: Kevin, I'll try that. Gerrat, it's possible; I'm new to Python (at least I've never used for anything as serious as what I'm doing now). However, I thought I'd used global similarly before, without this problem.

Comment: Is the `create_composite()` function is the same py file as the two `select_file_x()` functions? `global` only applies to the module everything is in -- Python doesn't have truly global variables.

Comment: martineau, yes all in the same .py file.

Comment: Kevin, I tried restructing to using self. I'm not sure where the problem is. It seems the problem is that filedialog.askdirectory() is not storing the directory as a string where it should. I changed it to a self, and initially defined the string as being equal to '' (blank). Then, though the dialog box comes up and a folder is selected, I still get this error when trying to open the file: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''`

Comment: can you show the full, actual stack trace?

Comment: Bryan, what's the quickest way to do that? I assume you mean something more than just the output on terminal?

Comment: Presumably you got more than just "NameError: name 'first_file' is not defined" -- you get a half dozen lines or more showing line numbers and the call stack.

Comment: @Jake , post full stack trace (default output in terminal). Also, this suggests you don't have a variable `first_file` in the outside scope

Comment: Is it possible that the `create_composite()` function is being called _before_ `select_file_1()` has been called? Otherwise `first_file` won't exist.

Comment: In `create_composite`, the global declarations are not needed for the read-only access to the names.

Answer (score 1):

The snippets you have posted work correctly, so long as `select_file_1()` and `select_file_2()` are called *before* `create_composite`.

If you are still having problems you need to create a complete, small, working bit of code that you can post so others can see the problem.

Oh, and `filedialog.askdirectory` returns the name of a directory, not of a file -- trying to open that is not a good idea.